# Formatting With MySQL using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am right now doing a project for school and my project involves MySQL and Python connectivity. Now I am also using the Tkinter module for my project. Now when I want to format my variable using the old method(with %s and %d) and also using the get() with my MySQL table an error is saying that it cannot format with %d and error is coming saying I cannot use an entry widget but must use a number. Please tell me what to do.

```
def register_insert():
global db
global pointer
top = Tk()
patient_name = Entry(top, width=30)
patient_name.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
label_1 = Label(top, text="Enter The Patients Name:")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
civil_id = Entry(top, width=30)
civil_id.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
label_2 = Label(top, text="Enter The Patients Civil_ID No:")
label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)
age = Entry(top, width=30)
age.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10)
label_3 = Label(top, text="Enter The Patients Age:")
label_3.grid(row=2, column=0)
phone_no = Entry(top, width=30)
phone_no.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10)
label_4 = Label(top, text="Enter The Patients Phone_No:")
label_4.grid(row=3, column=0)
date_1 = Entry(top, width=30)
date_1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10)
label_5 = Label(top, text="Enter The Patients Date Of Registering:")
label_5.grid(row=4, column=0)
address = Entry(top, width=30)
address.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10)
label_6 = Label(top, text="Enter The Patients Address:")
label_6.grid(row=5, column=0)
try:
    db = sql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', database='info', passwd='90603')
    pointer = db.cursor()
    pointer.execute("Insert into registration values('%s','%d','%d','%d','%s','%s')"
                    % (patient_name, civil_id, age, phone_no, date_1,
                       address))
    button = Button(top, text="Enter", command=enter)
    button.grid(row=6, coulmn=1, columnspan=2)
except Exception as e:
    msg.showerror("Error!!", e)
    db.close()
```

I do not know why an error is coming please help me out

Comment: Then why go for the old method, also post the entire error code. I think you might want to fix the indentation also of your code and `command=enter` seems undefined in this code, and how do you invoke `register_insert()`

Comment: You should use `patient_name.get()`, `civil_id.get()`, ..., etc, and use all `%s` in the SQL statement because `get()` returns string.  But the prefer way is using `placeholder`.

Comment: Ok. I do not know the new method. I was only taught the old method. I am still learning and I will try the new method and I will also try making it all strings and also see about using a placeholder. Thank You for the help.

Comment: I would invoke the function register_insert() later. That was not why the error was coming though.